# How to install a rubygem from inside a ruby script and require this gem afterwards?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to do something like this:

```
begin
  require 'progressbar'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "exception .. installing with gem"
  h = system 'gem install progressbar'
  puts "gem installed #{h}"
  require 'progressbar'
end
pbar = ProgressBar.new("test", 100)
100.times {sleep(0.1); pbar.inc}; pbar.finish
```

but obviously if you run this snippet, the progressbar gem is not available.

Comment: You should consider to use bundler If your script has external dependencies.

Comment: I agree with spickerman that this should not be done, it is likely to cause more problems than it solves compared to using Bundler. However, an answer which showed what `gem` is manipulating, and how to do same inside an already-running Ruby session, might be interesting.

Comment: Yeah .. using bundler is an option. My rubyprogram does not require everything upfront, because most people do not need to run this special piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this discussion: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/131346
Obviously calling `Gem.clear_paths` solves the issue. In total:

```
begin
  require 'progressbar'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "exception .. installing gem"
  h = system 'gem install progressbar'
  puts "gem installed #{h}"
  Gem.clear_paths
  require 'progressbar'
end
pbar = ProgressBar.new("test", 100)
100.times {sleep(0.1); pbar.inc}; pbar.finish
```